# Finding the minimum number of perfect squares to sum up to n

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the problem of finding the minimum number of perfect squares (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 9..) that sum up to `n`

Here's my recursive top-down approach:

```
import math

class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        dp = [math.inf] * (n + 1)
        dp[0] = 0
        dp[1] = 1 

        def solve(n: int):
            if dp[n] != math.inf:
                return dp[n]

            for i in range(n, 0, -1):
                if n - i * i >= 0:
                    sol = solve(n - i*i)
                    dp[i] = min(1 + sol, dp[i])

            return dp[n]

        solve(n)
        print(dp)

Solution().numSquares(12)
```

I can't put my finger on why this code doesn't yield the correct result. Can you please help my find the bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: according to Lagrange theorem, any number can be represented as a sum of **four** squares. So you can check if number is a perfect square, sum of two perfect squares, threes squares and, finally, four squates.

Comment: `dp[i]` should be `dp[n]`

Comment: What is the expected outcome? I feel like this is sooo overcomplicated, I would just take the int(np.floor(np.sqrt(n))) and substract the square of that from n so you take the biggest perfect square away from n and get a way smaller number and proceed with that.

Comment: What have you found out while debugging a small failing example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = [math.inf] * (n + 1)
        dp[0] = 0
        dp[1] = 1
        
        def solve(n: int):
            if dp[n] != math.inf:
                return dp[n]
            sol = math.inf
            for i in range(n, 0, -1):
                if n - i * i >= 0:
                    sol = min(sol, solve(n-i*i))
            dp[n] = sol+1
            
            return dp[n]
        
        return solve(n)
```

The above is the corrected version of your solution but it's still too slow since you check every number even if their squares are obviously greater than `n`. Below is an optimized version that passes LC's time limits:

```py
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = [math.inf] * (n + 1)
        dp[0] = 0
        dp[1] = 1
        
        def solve(n: int):
            if dp[n] != math.inf:
                return dp[n]
            sol = math.inf
            for i in range(1, n):
                if n - i * i >= 0:
                    sol = min(sol, solve(n-i*i))
                else:
                    break
            dp[n] = sol+1
            
            return dp[n]
        
        return solve(n)
```

But there is still room for optimization. A little bit:

```py
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = [math.inf] * (n + 1)
        dp[0] = 0
        dp[1] = 1
        
        def solve(n: int):
            if dp[n] != math.inf:
                return dp[n]
            sol = math.inf
            for i in range(1, math.floor(n**(1/2))+1):
                sol = min(sol, solve(n-i*i))
            dp[n] = sol+1
            
            return dp[n]
        
        return solve(n)
```

Another way to solve this is using a BFS approach. Imagine all the paths to get to `n` as a tree where the leafs are of value `n` and each movement to a neighboring node has a cost of one. In a BFS the first hit is the best hit since the costs are all equal:

```py
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int) -> int:
        deq = collections.deque([n])
        steps = 1
        
        while deq:
            n = len(deq)
            
            for _ in range(n):
                node = deq.popleft()
                for i in range(1, floor(node**(1/2))+1):
                    num = i**2
                    if num == node:
                        return steps
                    deq.append(node - num)
            steps += 1
```

As pointed out by Dmitry Bychenko, you can solve that using Lagrange's theorem. Here's a [nice write up and python solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/discuss/707526/Python-Fastest-O(sqrt(n))-solution-with-math-explanied.) about it.

Comment: You should add an explanation or note for the optimization as well imo

Comment: You are right, @AbhinavMathur. Will do that.